# Custom language strings Moodle Mobile

Tags: android, mobile, moodle

I am trying to add a custom language string in moodle 3.7+ under admin/mobile features to hide a menu item in the mobile app rather than edit it.

I would like to hide Space Usage from the sub menu in app settings. Is it possible to hide this using a custom lang string in moodle or is this more from coding within the app?

If someone can help me i would be grateful for the learning curve.

I understand how to edit the wording on the menu but not how to hide it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no setting in Moodle web to disable or hide that particular sub-menu item you mentioned. Also, I don't think you should use the language strings system to do this. I can think of two alternatives, though:

1. You could, of course, remove it from the template of the app (at `src/core/settings/pages/list/list.html`) and then publish a new app version.
2. Alternatively, hide it via CSS, since the app has this feature that allows each app client to inherit custom CSS from Moodle web: write a few lines of CSS specifying the selector for that particular `<a>` item (second item of the list of that settings page, or class and title of the item, etc.) and then a `display:none`. Put the CSS file within some publicly accessible address of your web server, and then set the URL to that CSS file in the Moodle web setting: `mobilecssurl`.

Comment: Hi Mitxel, thanks for your response. In relation to point 1 in your answer i cant seem to find that path in the moodle app.  I am using version 3.7.0.  There is a template folder in the root but no list.html.  Any idea's? Thanks again Andy

Comment: hello @Andy , I'm 100% sure it is there :P Check the repo for the moodle mobile app version 3.7.0: https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2/blob/master/src/core/settings/pages/list/list.html You may have to review your project folder structure :\

Comment: Hi Mitxel, i see from your link its there. I have been using this link https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile-phonegapbuild so i am starting to think i'm pulling this from the wrong source.

Comment: Hi @andy I see. I think that repo contains the correct version of the app, but I think it is pre-built already so you can build the different app binaries using the Phonegap Build cloud service (instead of XCode, Android Studio, etc.). Since the app is built already you won't find the `src` source code, but you can still theoretically modify the "compiled" JS code at `build`, then modify the JS responsible of rendering the item of that view (I suspect it's around `38.js`), but I have never tried to do modifications over a built project and I can not recommend anyone to do it.

Comment: Hi Mitxel, Many thanks for your response. I have tried to research what the few lines of CSS code would be but struggling as i am new to this and trying to learn as i go forward.  I have tried researching it on youtube tutorials but not having much joy. I understand from your 38.js that the selector is 'page-core-settings-list' for the list.html template. Is this something you can help me out with? I appreciate this is deviating off the original query but any help would be gratefully received. Just need to understand what this code would look like.